# For loop, syntax C error?

Tags: c, for-loop, syntax-error, convergence

Is there anything wrong in these "for" loops? About syntax..? It compiles. The results start to increase while the program running, without any physical sense. i and j indexes are right.  These loops are part of a long code but after debugging it seems that the mistake is not anywhere else.

```
for (i=0; i< *nbox; i++)  {
    for(j=0; j< *m1;j++) {
    bn[i][j] =bn[i][j]/dx[1];
                    }
    for(j=0; j< *m2;j++) {
    cn[i][j] =cn[i][j]/dx[1];
     }
}
```

---

```
for (i=0; i<=*npmax-1; i++)  {

    for(j=0; j< *m1;j++) {
        partic[j][i]= partic[j][i]*dx[1];
    }
    for(j=0; j< *m2;j++) { 
        partic[j+ *m1][i]=partic[j+ *m1][i]*dx[1];
    }
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: you have an unmatched number of parenthesis in your example. What results are increasing? Does your *m1 or *m2 or *npmax change while looping?

Comment: Now that I've fixed the indentation, you can see that you have one loop with the variable `i` nested inside another with the same variable.

Comment: @nio: Where is the unmatched parenthesis?

Comment: Your code needs some documenting comments so as to make it understandable.

Comment: @ Lightness Races in Orbit  The first one `{`

Comment: Looks like one `}` missing. Is it typo?

Comment: it was typo. could be that the *= is necessary?

Answer (score 1):

You reuse the `i` index inside the first loop.
Change it to something else and it should fix your problem.

Comment: What do you mean..? The two loops are separated, independent. They are inside the same c file, but in separated subprograms..

Comment: @beginner2707876 - well, why not use local i's?  You're just confusing us because we cannot see the scope of your indexes.